# Prevent div inside of list item to slide up

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my menu i have a list item with login fields :

```
                                 <li class='has-sub' onclick="LoginButtonClicked()" style="float: right">
                                     <a href='#' id="notificationList">
                                         <span>Log in2</span>

                                     </a>
                                     <ul class="loginBox" style="display: none; height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
                                         <li>
                                             <div id="Div1" style="background: #0fa1e0; padding: 4px;">

                                                 <input type="text" value="LoginName" />

                                                 <input type="text" value="Password" />
                                             </div>

                                         </li>
                                     </ul>
                                 </li>
```

when i click on li class LoginButtonClicked function gets fired and ul slides down:

```
var loginUserMenuChoosen = false;

function LoginButtonClicked() {
    console.log(loginUserMenuChoosen);
    if (loginUserMenuChoosen == false) {
        loginUserMenuChoosen = true;


        $('.loginBox').slideDown(200);


        //$('.masterPageNotifier').val("0");
    }
    else if (loginUserMenuChoosen == true) {
        loginUserMenuChoosen = false;
        $('.loginBox').slideUp(200);
    }
}
```

The problem here is, that when i select text fields inside list item it also keep sliding up. how do i prevent this?

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fAKzw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the click event propagation from the sub menu,

add id to the sub menu like this

```
<ul id="subMenu" class="loginBox" style="display: none; height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
```

then prevent the event propagation

```
$("#subMenu").click(function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
```

});

modifying Darren Davies code, check this http://jsfiddle.net/fAKzw/5/

Answer (score 1):

Give the `li` an ID:

```
<li id="liScrollDown" class='has-sub' style="float: right">
```

Then do:

```
$("#liScrollDown").click(function() {
     LoginButtonClicked();
});
```

Comment: @Timsen - it's because your markup is invalid.  I have closed the </ul> tag off and it works - http://jsfiddle.net/fAKzw/1/